# If $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a Cauchy sequence, then $(a_n ^2)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is also a Cauchy sequence

Tags: real-analysis, cauchy-sequences

If the sequence $\{a_n\}$ with $n∈\mathbb{N}$ is a Cauchy sequence, 
then $\{a_n^2\}_{n∈\mathbb{N}}$ is also a Cauchy sequence.
How do we prove it?

Comment: Do you know a real sequence converges iff it is a Cauchy sequences?

Comment: can you explain please?

Comment: Not before you answer my question, @Togepi

Comment: what is definition of cauchy sequence??

Comment: Yes I know but how do we relate {an} and {an2}? @Timbuc

Comment: $(a_n)_n$ is Cauchy, hence convergent. Hence, $(a_n^2)_n$ is ???

Comment: Here's another hint: in order to prove the Cauchy property of $\{a_n^2\}$ directly from the Cauchy property of $\{a_n\}$, you can use $a_n^2 - a_m^2 = (a_n - a_m)(a_n + a_m)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Directly from definition:

Take any $\;\epsilon>0\;$ . Since $\;\{a_n\}_{n\in\Bbb N}\;$ is a Cauchy sequence it is bounded, there exists $\;M\in\Bbb R\;$ s.t. for *any* $\;k\in\Bbb N\;,\;\;|a_k|\le M\;$ , and since it is also a Cauchy sequence there exists $\;N\in\Bbb N\;$ s.t. for all $\;n,m>N\;,\;\;|a_n-a_m|<\frac\epsilon{2M}\;$ , thus:

$$\forall\,n,m>N\;,\;\;|a_n^2-a_m^2|=|a_n-a_m|\,|a_n+a_m|\le\frac\epsilon{2M}\left(|a_n|+|a_m|\right)=\epsilon$$

and $\;\{a_n^2\}_{n\in\Bbb N}\;\;$ is Cauchy.

Comment: Thanks!! But where did $|a_n-a_m|<\frac\epsilon{2M}$ come from?

Comment: @Togepi, it comes from the fact that's a Cauchy sequence, of course.